# Find the third side of a right triangle

Tags: geometry

> (4) The equations of two of the sides of a triangle $ABC$ are
> $$
> x+2y= 8 \qquad \text{and} \qquad 2x+y=1
> $$
> Given that $A$ is the point $(2,-3)$ and the angle $ABC$ is a right angle, find
>
> - the equation of the third side
> - the coordinates of $B$

This is my understanding

[image]

My question is how to find the equation of third side, the condition is not enough???
I only have the coordinates of point a and b and two equation.

Comment: Would you mind at least turning the text, so that we don't have to twist our necks?

Comment: Notice that the right angle is $ABC$ - that means that the right angle is at $B$, not $A$ (contrary to your drawing). Therefore, I think the conditions **are** enough to solve the problem. You need to find the line perpendicular to $x+2y=8$ which goes through $(2,-3)$. There is only one such line.

Answer (score 1):

> The equation of the third side is  $y=2x-7$

$A$ is not on $x+2y=8$ and so $B$ is on this line.

$AB$ is perpendicular to $x+2y=8$ and so has gradient $2$. It passes through $A$ and so $AB$ has equation $y=2x-7$.

> The coordinates of $B$ are $(\frac{22}{5},\frac{9}{5})$

Solve the pair of simultaneous equations $x+2y=8$ and  $y=2x-7$.

Comment: Thank you for the information , appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite equation as:

$y= -\frac{1}{2}x+4$

$y= -2 x+1$

These two sides can not be perpendicular on each other. Also point (2, -3) does not satisfy first equation, but it does the second one. Therefore angle at this point must be $90^o$ that is the gradient of required line mus be :

$m= - \frac{1}{-2}=\frac{1}{2}$

Hence the equation of third side is:

$y+3=\frac{1}{2}(x-2)$, or, $y=\frac{1}{2}x-4$, or, $x-2y=8$

The coordinate of other vertices are:

$x-2y=8$

$x+2y=8$

Which gives  B: $(x, y)=(4, -2)$

$x+2y=8$

$2x+y=1$

Which gives, C: $(x, y)=(-2, 5)$

We can check this:

$AB^2=(4-2)^2+(-2+3)^2=5$

$AC^2=(2+2)^2+(-3-5)^2=80$

$BC^2=(4+2)^2+(-2-5)^2=85$

So $BC^2=AB^2+AC^2$

Comment: Thank you for the information, appreciate!